# In java, if the method , static variable and variable of the class are instanced multiplely As instancing the class multiplely

Tags: java, jvm

In java, if the method , static variable and variable of the class are instanced multiplely As instancing the class multiplely.

For Example:

```
class Person {
    private String name;
    public static int age;

    public void getName() {
       return name;
    }

    public static void getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}
```

When instance the class "Persion" 3 times:

```
 Persion p1 = new persion();
 Persion p2 = new persion();
 Persion p3 = new persion();
```

If the variable "name", "age" and function "getName()", "getAge" is  instanced 3 times?

Comment: Shortly yes, all members get instanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the variable "name", "age" and function "getName()", "getAge()" is instanced 3 times?

1. `name` is not `static`, therefore it is **instanced thrice**.
2. `age` is `static`, therefore it is **not instanced thrice**.
3. `getName()` is also **separate for each object**
4. `getAge()` is `static`, **therefore same for all objects**

`static` basically means that it is same **across all the objects of that class**.

Answer (score 0):

Static variable are defined only once - `static` keyword means that that don't belong to object, but to class.

Variable `name` is not `static` so it will be initialized when object is created.

So, if you create three `Person` object you will have 3 `name` variables (for each of your `Person` object and only one `age` static variable.

Answer (score 0):

in java `static` variable only acquire one memory adress once same with `static` method even if you create a copy of many Persion only one memory is stored